# Unable to create a readonly sqlite store in Core Data: Cocoa Error 260

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to create a `NSSQLiteStoreType` with the readonly option (`NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption`). This fails if the sqlite file doesn't exist (see code below). If it does exist, the store is added without any errors.

The error I get is `Cocoa Error 260`:

```
NSFileReadNoSuchFileError = 260,     // Read error (no such file)
```

So it looks like CoreData tries to read a file that doesn't exist, instead of creating a new one...

It seems that when adding `NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption`  you can only open a previously existing store, but not create one. This doesn't make sense to me.

Is there any way to create a brand new readonly store in Core Data?

If not, is there some workaround?

```
// DB URL
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *dbURL = [[fm URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                           inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
dbURL = [dbURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"store.sqlite"];


// Object Model
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSAssert([fm fileExistsAtPath:[modelURL path]], @"File not found");

NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

// Store Coordinator
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coord = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

// Add a readonly SQLite store
NSError *err = nil;
NSPersistentStore *store = [coord addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                               configuration:nil URL:dbURL
                                                     options:@{NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption : @YES}
                                                       error:&err];
if (store == nil) {
    // I get a Cocoa Error 260.
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm being obtuse, but why would you want a brand new, empty store to be read-only?  Putting that aside, could you open it read/write, close it, and then reopen it as read-only?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new, empty, read-only store makes no sense, and the results you're seeing are exactly what would be expected. By specifying read-only you are specifically indicating that no file should be written, so as a result.... no file is written.

It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish. If the file *were* created, you would not be able to use it, since it would contain no data and since the read-only flag would prevent you from adding any data. An empty file would be exactly as useful.

But no, there is no way to tell Core Data to create a new persistent store file but have that file be read only, mainly because such an operation would be nonsensical and useless.

If you have some reason to want a persistent store file which is both empty and unwritable (and if you do, please share), you would need to

1. Add the persistent store *without* the read-only flag
2. Call `removePersistentStore:error:` to remove that persistent store
3. Add the persistent store again, *with* the read-only flag.

You will now have a persistent store which contains no data, and which you are prevented from adding data to.

A simpler alternative that is just as effective is to not create the file in the first place. An empty read-only persistent store serves literally no purpose at all, so the easy approach is to just not bother creating it.