# How Can I Tell If My NSManagedObject Resides in a Read Only NSPersistentStore?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I would like to add read-only example/tutorial data to my Core Data based macOS app.

I will include an SQL file in my application bundle containing the example data. My NSPersistentContainer will have 2 NSPersistentStores, one writable and one read only. I will only have a default configuration for my model since both stores will have the same model.

My UI will need to know if the data displayed is read only or not, for example, to stop this data being draggable.

I know that NSManagedObject does not support a readonly state, see and : [Is it possible to return NSManagedObjects as read-only in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33292161/978300) ...and the docs.

I think the best approach would be to add a readonly property to my NSManagedObject derived class that can be queried where necessary. However, I can't see how I could easily set this property! I can't find a direct link to an NSPersistentStore from an NSManagedObject.

I could set up an NSFetchRequest and specify the read only store and see if the NSManagedObject is in it, but that seems a little ridiculous.

Am I missing something more obvious here please?

Comment: Thinking aloud: could you do a fetch from the read-only store using a one-off, temporary context, to retrieve the relevant objectIDs, and compare to that list in awakeFromFetch to set your readonly property?

Comment: Thank you @pbasdf. That might be pretty reasonable because the set of read-only items will not be huge. There I was assuming there might be a little something straightforward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to pbasdf for his suggestion...

I could find no straight-forward way to achieve this. I had to move away from using `NSPersistentContainer` to simplify my Core Data stack. However, I think this is a fairly elegant solution if you need a small subset of your graph to be readonly.

I subclassed `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to cache the `NSManagedObjectIDs` of any readonly store added to it:

```
class GraphStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
{
    override init(managedObjectModel model: NSManagedObjectModel)
    {
        readOnlyTestContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        super.init(managedObjectModel: model)
        readOnlyTestContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self

        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(forName: .NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChange,
                         object: self, queue: nil)  { [unowned self] notification in

            // userInfo will be in this form for add/remove keys - not supporting migration here
            guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: [NSPersistentStore]] else {
                unhandledError("Invalid userInfo for NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChange.") }

            userInfo[NSAddedPersistentStoresKey]?.forEach { self.didAddStore($0) }
            userInfo[NSRemovedPersistentStoresKey]?.forEach { self.didRemoveStore($0) }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default
            .removeObserver(self, name: .NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChange, object: self)
    }

    private func didAddStore(_ store: NSPersistentStore) {
        guard store.isReadOnly else { return }

        var addedObjects = Set<NSManagedObjectID>()
        baseEntityNames.forEach { entityName in
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entityName)
            fetchRequest.affectedStores = [store]

            do {
                let addedEntityObjects = try readOnlyTestContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
                addedObjects = addedObjects.union(addedEntityObjects.map { $0.objectID })
            } catch {
                unhandledError("Failed to fetch all \(entityName) for read only check: \(error)") }
        }

        readOnlyObjects[store.identifier] = addedObjects
    }

    private func didRemoveStore(_ store: NSPersistentStore) {
        guard store.isReadOnly else { return }
        readOnlyObjects.removeValue(forKey: store.identifier)
    }

    /// Returns the minimum set of entities that can be fetched for readonly checking
    private lazy var baseEntityNames: [String] = {
        return managedObjectModel.entitiesByName.compactMap { $1.superentity == nil ? $0 : nil }
    }()

    private var readOnlyTestContext: NSManagedObjectContext

    /// Readonly objectIDs keyed per persistent store
    private var readOnlyObjects = [String : Set<NSManagedObjectID>]()

    internal func isObjectReadOnly(_ objectID: NSManagedObjectID) -> Bool {
        return readOnlyObjects.contains(where: { $1.contains(objectID) } )
    }
}
```

I then added an extension to `NSManagedObject` to that queries its `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` for read-only status:

```
public extension NSManagedObject
{
    /// Does this managed object reside in a read-only persistent store?
    var isReadOnly: Bool {
        guard let coordinator = managedObjectContext?
            .persistentStoreCoordinator as? GraphStoreCoordinator else {
            unhandledError("Should only check readonly status in a GraphStoreCoordinator") }

        return coordinator.isObjectReadOnly(objectID)
    }
}
```